# ExpressJS router POST method does not work

Tags: express

I'm looking at Expressjs and following the examples I've seen, they are all very simple which is awesome.  However, what am I missing with POST method that it does not work.  Below is the code in app.js

````
const app = express()
const router = express.Router();
const port = 3000

app.use('/qbiit', router);

router.route('/on')
.post((req, res) => {
    res.send('POST')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('HOME')
})




app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})```

I also created a separated express project using express-generator.  The GET method works.  POST does not.  What I want for post is for it to do something ```http://localhost:3000/qbiit/on```
````

Answer (score 0):

The router can be in a separate js file. So that you can import and use in app.js.

```js
router.js
---------------
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const usersController = require("../controller/usersController");

// UsersController
router.route("/").post(usersController.createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

```js
app.js
---------------
const usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
```